# How to use var to create an object using the GetType() method?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, gettype

I'm fed up of writing the lines of code:

```
SomeUIElement ui = new SomeUIElement();
Grid.Children.Clear();
Grid.Children.Add(ui);
```

So I decided to write a method that would determine the type of the element then clear children and add it to the grid.

Something like this:

```
    private void GridChildren(UIElement uc)
    {
        var element = uc.GetType();
        Grid.Children.Clear();
        Grid.Children.Add(element);
    }
```

Which I could then call like this:

```
GridChilren(UserControl);
```

However I keep getting the error:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'System.Windows.UIElement'
```

Any ideas on how I can determine the type of `usercontrol` being passed to my method?

**EDIT:**

I could call this by creating the instance first then clearing and adding to the grid. However that is not my question.

Yes, it would be more convenient, but for the purpose of this question assume that I *ONLY* want to understand how I can create an instance of a type without writing it out myself.

Comment: you need to pass it an instance (`ui`) instead of the type

Comment: Damn, I thought that may be the case. I just wanted to be really lazy and pass through just the type! Man....

Comment: How would that even help? You could always use `Activator.CreateInstance` to make a new one, but that doesn't buy you much...

Comment: Why are you using `GetType` ? You are not finding controls of the same type, you are just clearing and adding controls to `Grid` control.

Comment: `I'm fed up of writing the lines of code` - then learn to use WPF properly by using XAML and DataBinding instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though you want to create an instance of a `UIElement` type and add it as the only child element of a grid.

The first line of your code (`var element = uc.GetType()`) returns an object of type `Type`, which results in the exception when you try to add it to the grid's `Children` collection (because that expects you to be adding a `UIElement` object, not a `Type` object).

You could have written your method like this:

```
private void GridChildren(UIElement uc)
{
    Grid.Children.Clear();
    Grid.Children.Add(uc);
}
```

And then you would call it like this:

```
SomeUIElement ui = new SomeUIElement();
GridChildren(ui);
```

but that's only saving you one line over the "longhand" version.

The following method will **create** and add a new `UIElement` to **any** kind of `Panel` control:

```
public void SetPanelChild<T>(Panel panel)
    where T : UIElement, new()
{
    T element = new T();
    panel.Children.Clear();
    panel.Children.Add(element);
}
```

The advantage of using generics here is that you don't need to bother with `Activator.CreateInstance()`. You would call the method like this:

```
SetPanelChild<TextBlock>(myPanel);
```

However when you find yourself creating controls programmatically like this there's probably a better way of doing it that leverages what WPF has to offer, such as the MVVM pattern and data binding.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `Activator.CreateInstance()` method, which will create an instance of a type using Reflection.

You will still need to cast it.

Alternatively (depending on how you're calling it), use a generic type parameter instead.

Comment: I looked into that after seeing one of the comments. Could you post an example?